# Using generator to fill integer values in 2-D array

Tags: python-3.x

I want to use the below code (am supposed to not use map(), for an online programming site as gives error on that of : TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable
):

```
arr[i][j] = [int(input("Input score").strip().split()[:l]) for j in range(n) for i in range(t)]
```

instead of the below working version:

```
for i in range(t):   
    for j in range(n):
        arr[i][j] = map(int, input("Input score").strip().split())[:l]
```

but the error is (assume so) based on providing a list instead of individual values, as stated below:

TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

Unable to find a solution by any alternate way, say convert rhs (of desired soln.) to a string in first step & then assign to lhs in the second step; as need assign to arr[i][j].

P.S. Need to make the solution use the individual and row-wise values of arr, as say need find row-wise sum of values or even individual values. The below code uses the row-wise arr values to fill up total.

```
for i in range(t): 
    for j in range(n):
        # Find sum of all scores row-wise 
        sum = 0
        for m in arr[i][j]:
            sum += m
        total[i][j] = sum
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a nested list comprehension as follows:

```
t = int(input("Input number of tests: ")) 
n = int(input("Input number of rows: "))#.strip().split()) 

total = [[sum([int(i) for i in input("Input score: ").split()]) for j in range(n)] for t_index in range(t)]

print(total)
```

Example of an input-output pair:

```
Input number of tests: 2
Input number of rows: 3
Input score: 1 2 3
Input score: 2 3 4
Input score: 3 4 5
Input score: 4 5 6
Input score: 5 6 7
Input score: 6 7 8
[[6, 9, 12], [15, 18, 21]]
```

Comment: I changed to : total = [[sum([int(i) for i in input("Input score: ").split()[:l]]) for j in range(n)] for t_index in range(t)]

Comment: Kindly  join the chatroom for my code at : https://onlinegdb.com/H1mR3VjvV , for coin change problem c code using memoization. Unable to understand its workings. Please join the chatroom at : https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89042/notation-for-statement-with-nested-iff

Answer (score 2):

You can map your nested `for` loops:

```
for i in range(t):   
    for j in range(n):
        arr[i][j] = map(int, input("Input score").strip().split())[:l]
```

to a list comprehension like:

```
arr = [map(int, input("Input score").strip().split())[:l] for i in range(t) for j in range(n)]
```

And without a `map` like:

```
arr = [[int(k) for k in input("Input score").strip().split())[:l]] 
       for i in range(t) for j in range(n)]
```

Comment: Sorry, did not mention that am not supposed to use map().

Comment: No, a geeksforgeeks site practice sample question, not even contest.

Comment: But need arr[i][j] to have row-wise sum of values. Please tell me how to use arr in a loop for processing row-wise or indl. values. Please see the edit above.